# Using Alt key like the mac command (⌘) key for copy/paste

Tags: command-line, keyboard, shortcut-keys

I'm coming to Linux from mac and most of the command (<kbd>⌘</kbd>) shortcuts I'm used to translate in a straightforward way to Linux using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>.

But copy/paste is awkward. In terminal I need to use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> modifier (since `^C` and `^V` serve other purposes in that context). This adds both physical (extra press) and mental overhead (I have to remember which shortcut to use based on which application I'm currently in).

I started wondering, why not configure my machine to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> instead <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for copy/paste? That would make them physically identical to what I'm used to on mac, and it doesn't seem like anything's currently using those keys.

I'm a heavy user of:

- terminal
- vim
- emacs
- chromium
- slack

I already changed the copy/paste shortcuts in my terminal, but I'm wondering three things:

1. Is there a good way to configure this globally, rather than ad-hoc per application?
2. Is there some other purpose that <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> usually serve in a Linux environment?
3. Is there any other reason *not* to do this?

### Update

The problem, I found, with changing terminal copy/paste to use <kbd>Alt</kbd> was that it made it even *harder* to remember which key to use (am I on Mac? on Linux? on Linux in the terminal?).

I'm now trying a different compromise, which so far I find works (for me): use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> in the terminal and leave it at <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> elsewhere. I like this because:

- <kbd>Alt</kbd> is more comfortable than <kbd>Shift</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> remains part of the equation, and I find that consistency easier to remember
- I have to juggle <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> anyway, depending on whether I'm on Mac or Linux; easier to juggle those two keys than to introduce <kbd>Shift</kbd> to the mental overhead as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking for the same answer, but I haven't found a good solution yet.

In the interim, I've swapped my <kbd>alt</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> which helps with keeping my muscle memory.

This might work for you in the mean time:

```
setxkbmap -layout 'us,us' -option 'ctrl:swap_lalt_lctl'
```

And you might have to keep Gnome from resetting your layout:

```
sudo gsettings set org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.keyboard active false
```

Hopefully someone a little bit more knowledgeable will provide a solution to keep from using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> in the terminal.

[EDIT] Turns out the settings don't last past a reboot. I set this in my **xorg.conf**

```
Section "InputDevice"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
  Identifier     "Keyboard0"                                                                                                                                                                    
  Driver         "kbd"                                                                                                                                                                          
  Option         "XkbRules" "xorg"                                                                                                                                                              
  Option         "XkbModel" "pc105"                                                                                                                                                             
  Option         "XkbLayout" "us"                                                                                                                                                               
  Option         "XkbOptions" "ctrl:swap_lalt_lctl"                                                                                                                                             
EndSection
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I prefer setting xkb-options to `caps:ctrl_modifier,shift:both_capslock` so I can use caps as ctrl, and as esc when tapped (using xcape). But I think I've found a good compromise on the copy/paste thing. I'll update my post above.